# How to display two (or more) different measures on a map?

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, choropleth

I would like to create a data visualization consisting of a geographical map (for example a country divided by regions) and show two measures.
I'll explain it better: I have for example a country C composed by 4 regions: R1, R2. R3, R4.
Then I have a dataset like this:

```
2017 |  A  |  B  | 
------------------
  R1 | 100 |  45 |
  R2 |   5 |   7 |
  R3 |  20 |  18 |
  R4 |  33 |  74 |


2016 |  A  |  B  | 
------------------
  R1 |  90 |  25 |
  R2 |  15 |  51 |
  R3 | 120 |   1 |
  R4 |   5 |  71 |
```

In other words, I have two measures for each region: measure A and measure B (which could be for example the number of inhabitants and the number of coffee consumed per day) for several years, in this example only two.
How can I view this information in the best possible way?

I thought of something like this: showing the measure A with the colors (the darker the color, the higher the value) and the measure B with the pattern (the more the pattern is dense and the higher the value).
In this way:

[image]

Is there a better way to do it? I would like to show the correlation between the two measures.
And if I had more measures to show? So not just two but 3 or 4?

The aim is to obtain a good visualization from a visual and informative point of view.
In the end I think I will use d3.js and it will be an interactive data visualization.
But here I would like to make a generic speech, independent of the language used.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want has a technical name: this is a *bivariate choropleth*.

In a normal choropleth, you encode a given variable using a pattern or a colour. In a bivariate choropleth, you use two variables to create the patter or the colour (here is a good [post about it by Alberto Cairo](http://www.thefunctionalart.com/2017/12/dont-refrain-from-using-uncommon.html), and [here another nice explanation](http://www.joshuastevens.net/cartography/make-a-bivariate-choropleth-map/)).

So, basically, we'll create a grid combining two variables:

[image]

<sup>Source: http://www.joshuastevens.net/cartography/make-a-bivariate-choropleth-map/</sup>

The user will decode that information like this: the horizontal gradient (from pale grey to green) shows one variable, and the vertical gradient (from pale grey to pink) shows another one.

[image]

<sup>Source: http://www.joshuastevens.net/cartography/make-a-bivariate-choropleth-map/</sup>

The most complicated thing here is, of course, creating the colours. There are several ways for doing this, based on your two variables. In the following demo, my approach is creating two scales, one for each variable, and interpolating the colours in the `fill` attribute:

```js
var w = h = 200;
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);
var data = d3.range(5).reduce(function(arr, elem) {
  return arr.concat(d3.range(5).map(function(d) {
    return {
      col: elem,
      row: d
    }
  }))
}, []);
var scale1 = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range(["gainsboro", "green"])
  .domain([0, 4]);
var scale2 = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range(["gainsboro", "#222"])
  .domain([0, 4]);
var rects = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", d => d.col * 40)
  .attr("y", d => d.row * 40)
  .attr("width", 39)
  .attr("height", 39)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([scale1(d.col), scale2(d.row)])(0.5)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

In the above demo I'm using intensity and saturation for the two variables. In the horizontal axis, the colour goes from a less saturated to a more saturated green. On the vertical axis, the colour goes from a lighter to a darker tone.

Finally, it's worth mentioning that a **BI**variate choropleth encodes only two variables. If you want to encode more than two (which I do not advise, two is hard enough for the user), you'll have to come up with another feature.

Comment: What a great answer, again! Are you sure about being allowed to embed the images, though?

Comment: @altocumulus No, I'm not, I'll check this.

Comment: There is a copyright note on that blog, but it doesn't hurt to ask! I'd drop them a line asking for permission.

Comment: @altocumulus The author allowed it. Thanks for the note.